# Getting a circular import error in django urls

Tags: django

I'm getting the following circular import error in the project level `urls.py` file:

`ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'pres_value.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.`

To be clear, `pres_value` is the project level and `present` is the app level.  So apparently the error is occurring in the project level `urls` file.  The app has been registered in the `settings.py` file.

Any help on what's wrong here is appreciated.

Project level `pres_value/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('present/', include('present.urls')),
]
```

App level `present/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import HomePageView, PresentValueView, AboutPageView, ResultView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('pv/', PresentValueView.as_view(), name='present_value'),
    path('result/', ResultView.as_view(), name='result'),
]
```

`settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'present',
]
```

Directory structure:

```
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── pres_value
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── present
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── present
│   │       ├── about.html
│   │       ├── home.html
│   │       ├── pv.html
│   │       └── result.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── footer.html
    ├── header.html
    └── nav.html
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .forms import PresentForm
from .models import PresentValue

# Create your views here.
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'present/home.html'

class PresentValueView(CreateView):
    model = PresentValue
    template_name = 'present/pv.html'
    # fields = ['first', 'second']
    success_url = reverse('result')

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'present/about.html'  ## this is where I show an error

class ResultView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'present/result.html'
```

Comment: Everything seems good, can you paste your `settings.py` and screenshot of directory structure here??

Comment: Sure, just added.  Only included the ```INSTALLED_APPS``` section of the settings.py.  Let me know if you'd like something else.

Comment: In `settings.py` section where `ROOT_URLCONF ` is defined.

Comment: Here you go:  ```ROOT_URLCONF = 'pres_value.urls'```

Comment: otherwise maybe some imports in views.py are causing that ?

Comment: Can you post your views.py also ?

Comment: I'm using VisualStudio and have an error (red dot) showing on one line of the ```views.py``` file, but as far as I can tell it's the same as the rest.  I've nested templates into a ```present/templates/present/<html files>``` structure.  Adding ```views.py``` above now.

Comment: Go ahead post that part. Your urls are fine. I think its caused by circular import. Need to have a look into view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The circular import is caused by `reverse()`.

> **Solution:** Use `reverse_lazy`.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class PresentValueView(CreateView):
    model = PresentValue
    template_name = 'present/pv.html'
    # fields = ['first', 'second']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('result')
```

Comment: @jpanknin, Try the solution and let me know if this works for you?

Comment: Just tried and it worked.  Never would have figured that out. Thank you!

Comment: That's a tricky bug. The reason why it happens is that the class body is evaluated at definition time (when the module is imported). It would also be avoided if you have a get_success_url method. `get_success_url(): return reverse('result')`